# Select two columns from the table via linq

Tags: c#, linq

I use the query below to get all columns(20 more) in Entity Framework Linq. Because of out of memory exception, I only want to get two of them. One is "FileName", the other one is "FilePath". How to modify my code?

```
var query = DBContext.Table1
    .Where(c => c.FacilityID == facilityID && c.FilePath != null && c.TimeStationOffHook < oldDate)
    .OrderBy(c => c.FilePath)
    .Skip(1000)
    .Take(1000)
    .ToList();
foreach(var t in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine(t.FilePath +"\\"+t.FileName);
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
var query = DBContext.Table1.Where(c => c.FacilityID == facilityID && c.FilePath != null && c.TimeStationOffHook < oldDate)
                            .OrderBy(c => c.FilePath)
                            .Skip(1000)
                            .Take(1000)
                            .Select(c => new { c.FilePath, c.FileName })
                            .ToList();
foreach(var t in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine(t.FilePath +"\\"+t.FileName);
}
```

You need to use [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb548891.aspx).

Comment: just a question : is is faster to Select subpart before of after ordering / skipping /taking ? Or doesn't it change anything in an EF context ?

Comment: Well since everything before your `.ToList()` is translated into a database query. You need not worry about it.

Comment: The runtime will generate SQL before executing it (on the call to `ToList`). The simplest way to find out would be to log the SQL through the `DBContext` and compare the different permutations.

Answer (score 4):

Just select out two of the columns:

```
DBContext.Table1.Select(c => new { c.FileName, c.FilePath });
```

Answer (score 2):

How about something like

```
using (var entity = new MyModel(ConnectionString))
            {
                var query = (from myTable in entity.theTable
                            where myTable.FacilityID == facilityID &&
                               myTable.FilePath != null &&
                               myTable.TimeStationOffHook < oldDate
                            orderby myTable.FilePath
                            select new
                            {
                                myTable,FileName,
                                myTable.FilePath
                             }).Skip(1000).Take(1000).ToList();
//do what you want with the query result here
            }
```